# How to return string from main function?

Tags: python, subprocess

How can I get string as return in this script?

main.py

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import os
import sys

child = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "child.py")
command = [sys.executable, child, "test"]
process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
process.communicate()
print(process.poll())
```

child.py

```
import sys

def main(i):
    return i*3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
```

I get only 0.
I think get response from `print()` and `process.communicate()` not the best way.

Comment: Python can't return strings to the OS - it can only return integers, like any other process. That `main` returns a string is meaningful only within Python.

Comment: @ForceBru: but ... what if I implement an OS that requires a string as a return value instead of a number? Can't I run python then?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I look forward to WellerOS.

Comment: @ThomasWeller you send it to the `subprocess.PIPE` or `sys.stdout`

Comment: @ThomasWeller, I guess you could provide a custom libc to link against, and that libc would make the `exit` function take a string and call the appropriate system call. Then you'd need to link Python against this libc, maybe hack around in its internals a bit - and it should be good to go. However, it's not entirely clear where to store that string. Integers can be copied around easily and stored in registers, but strings may need to be stored on the heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processes can't return values in the same sense a function can.

They can only set an exit code (which is the 0 you get).

You can, however, use stdin and stdout to communicate between the main script and `child.py`.

To "return" something from a child, just print the value you want to return.

```
# child.py
print("Hello from child")
```

The parent would do something like this:

```
process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = Popen.communicate()
assert stdout == "Hello from child"
```